# Where can one find a dead server's MySQL version?

Tags: mysql, linux

I'd like to know if there's any way to find out exactly which version of MySQL was installed on a server that is no longer running.  It's possible to browse through its filesystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ strings /usr/bin/mysql |egrep "^[1-9]\."
5.1.49
```

Comment: On my server it outputs 5.5.15
4.<I=
2.#ZB

Comment: Well maybe 5.5.15 your mysql version then?

Comment: Yes, but in 3 lines with stupid chars, you may enhance it with sort or what ever

Comment: But I think this is the only distro-independent way to get the version, if you don't want to or can't run the binaries.

Comment: Mostly a note to self: "strings" is part of the "binutils" package for Debian.

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out for Debian, just examine the installed changelog file: `/usr/share/doc/mysql-server-X.Y/changelog*.gz`

... where "X.Y" represents a major/minor version.

For example:

```
zcat /usr/share/doc/mysql-server-5.0/changelog*.gz | less
```

Comment: Not all distros has changelog*.gz, I have RHEL 5.4 : less /usr/share/doc/mysql-server-X.Y/changelog*.gz: No such file or directory

Comment: Just because my answer doesn't work for your RHEL 5.4 doesn't invalidate my answer for Debian! I specified that it was a Debian solution, too!

Answer (score 0):

if you have mysql client installed on target machine you can use

```
mysql -V
```

or if only server binaries are installed you can use

```
mysqld -V
```